# HTTP iframe in an SSL encrypted page

Tags: html, iframe, ssl

I have a website (clubdivisionals.com) with an SSL certificate enabled. On the live stream page of my site, I tried embedding a Twitch.TV video feed and chat box. The video feed is a flash player that is served via HTTPS while the chat box is an iframe that does not have SSL encryption. By default, web browsers such as Chrome and Firefox block the chat box because it's an iframe using HTTP served on an HTTPS website. Obviously, the iframe is not serving malicious content, but the web browser doesn't know this.

Is there a way around this without telling users to load "unsafe script?"

EDIT: one solution I could picture is disabling HTTPS only on the live stream page. Is there a way to do this using .htaccess? I can also provide the code to my .htaccess if you need it.

EDIT: Here is a solution I discovered on my own by editing the .htaccess file to disable SSL on the live stream page:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^livestream.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !livestream.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I'm not well versed in .htaccess's syntax, so please let me know if there is an issue with what I am doing or if there's a simpler way of doing it.

Comment: "*Obviously, the iframe is not serving malicious content, but the web browser doesn't know this.*". It's certainly not obvious, since it's plain HTTP and doesn't have the protection normally offered by HTTPS.

Comment: By obvious I meant I am not a hacker, nor is the service provided through the iframe malicious. I further clarified that the web browser naturally will not distinguish regardless. So by saying its obvious, I mean it's obvious to a human, not to a computer.

Comment: What I meant is that the point of using HTTPS isn't to protect users from malicious sites (users would still be vulnerable), it's to protect against eavesdropping or MITM attackers between the website and the browser. Whether or not you trust that site has no bearing on the requirements to use HTTPS (or not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not have control on content inside iframe. I-frame URL must work on HTTPS, so chat box URL must adopt SSL. You may disable HTTPS on specific page only if your webpage not containing log-in, sign-up options.

Comment: Yeah that's what I assumed as well. The live stream page does not have any private information, so I think disabling SSL on that page would be the best way to go. I made an edit on my original post with the solution I came up with. Do you know if there's any issues with what I did?

Comment: There is no issue in disabling SSL for any webpage only if you haven't log-in option.